# How to handle ParserError in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data contains several dates in different format:

| event | team1 | team2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| practice | 7/16/2022 | 7/18 |
| gameday | July 17 2022 | showtime |

I am trying to convert all dates into the same format(i.e. 07/16/2022) using parser.parse, but I'm getting ParseError when the date is 'showtime'. How can I handle ParserError and replace the non-date input into a random date('showtime' into random date mm/dd/yyyy)? Thank you.

`from dateutil.parser import parse`

```
df['team1'] = parse(df['team1'])
df['team2'] = parse(df['team2'])
```

Comment: Please show your code (minimal reproducible example)

Comment: could you also include the error that python outputs when you run your code that would

Comment: Just catch the exception by wrapping your statement in a try/except statement.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too elegant and may miss additional edge cases for odd dates, but maybe this will help with your immediate issue as long as missing years will be assumed to be 2022 for example.

```
import pandas as pd


year = "2022"
data = {
    "event": ["practice", "gameday"],
    "team1": ["7/16/2022", "July 17 2022"],
    "team2": ["7/18", "showtime"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


for column in ["team1", "team2"]:
    df[column] = df[column].apply(
        lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x if year in x else f"{x}/{year}", errors="coerce")
    ).map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if pd.notnull(x) else "")

print(df)
```